# Missing Microsoft Word files

Tags: microsoft-word

I am missing some saved docx files.  They did not turn up anywhere in a search of my entire c: drive.

I do not think that it got deleted, because I once had a file disappear before (one of the ones that is currently missing), and then it randomly turned up later.

I have saved files while running different versions of the normal template, and for some reason I think that possibly files that were saved while running some other template are not showing up.

Where/how should I look for my files?

Comment: Why don't you just use the recent document feature of Word to located the last location Word thought the file was at?

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I'm not sure how to do that, and it isn't a recent document - probably from about 11 months ago.

Comment: Alright.  So search all drives on your computer that were connected 11 months ago.  If you still cannot find it at that point then the file isn't on those drives.  I assume you can search for a string contained within the filenames using a wildcard character if required.  There isn't much we can do, if your searching for the file, and no results are found then the files don't exist on the storage device(s).

Comment: Files do not randomly disappear and reappear. They might not be visible in Word, but not being locatable anywhere on the drive is an entirely different thing.

Comment: If you use different users, you can't search anyone else's folders.

Comment: File -> Recent Documents will show you all documents Word opened, in the basic configuration, its the last 15 documents.